# not enough space for ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

i have TextView and ListView on LinearLayout, unfortunately on small screen i have not enough space for ListView(i mean it display about 0.5row). Is it possible to scroll up everything together.? Is in SDK any alternative for ListView that i can use for it.? Or maybe You got other idea how to make it userfriendly.?

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/studio"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is this </LinearView> doing, i dont see any opening tag for that

Comment: nothing, its dont even exist, its my mistake in copy paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There is a better solution for this instead of adding title to the main layout you can add that title to another layout and inflate that layout as header to the listview.

Like this -:

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.title, myListView, false);
myListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>


title.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/studio"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are my hero :) that is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the sizes and weights that you have assigned to various components. Assign proper weights to the listview and the text views layouts and it should work fine on any screen. e.g do some thing like this :

```
    <LinearLayout 
          android:id= "@+id/parent_layout"
          android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          android:layout_width = "match_parent"
          android:weightSum = "1.0"
          android:orientation = "vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
             android:id= "@+id/text_views_layout"
             android:layout_height = "0dp"
             android:layout_width = "match_parent"
             android:layout_weight = "0.7" 
          >
              <!-- place your text views here -->

          </LinearLayout>

          <ListView
             android:id ="@+id/list"
             android:layout_height = "0dp"
             android:layout_width ="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight = "0.3" 
          >
          </ListView> 

   </LinearLayout>
```

Note: you can specify any weights proportion for the textview_layout and the listview (i have set it to 0.7 : 0.3) but remember what ever weights you assign to them, they must sum up to the weight sum of the parent which is 1.0 in this case. Otherwise you might see unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `LinearLayout` with the 2 `TextView`s as a header view for the `ListView` using [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score -1):

There is `ScrollView` which could solve your problem, for example

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
    ......
   //More code here

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

but remember Scroll View can only have only and only one child, and that child could have its own further child but ScrollView could have only one child.  My this code is to give you idea it will not work by just copy and paste you have to made width , height etc adjustment according to your need

Comment: Using a ListView inside a ScrollView will make the ListView think that it has an infinate amount of available height - meaning all the view recycling and optimizations of the ListView will go to waste - all of its row's views will be created at once, rather than just the visible ones

Comment: if you fix the height of ListView, it will never happen

Comment: True, but unless you determine that dynamically in the layout pass, you're hard coding the size of a view which may not look good on all devices (even if you're careful with your qualifiers).